# How to download multiple urls using wget using a single command?

Tags: windows, download, wget, gnu

I am using following command to download a single webpage with all its images and js using wget in win7:

`wget -E -H -k -K -p -e robots=off -P /Downloads/ http://www.vodafone.de/privat/tarife/red-smartphone-tarife.html`

It is downloading the html as required, but when I tried to pass on a text file having a list of 3 urls to download, it didn't give any output, below is the command I am using:

`wget -E -H -k -K -p -e robots=off -P /Downloads/ -i ./list.txt -B 'http://'`

I tried this also:

`wget -E -H -k -K -p -e robots=off -P /Downloads/ -i ./list.txt`

This text file had urls `http://` prepended in it

`list.txt` contains list of 3 urls which I need to download using a single command. Please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

*-i ./list.txt* looks more like Unix parameter. Try with *.\list.txt* or like this:

```
wget -E -H -k -K -p -e robots=off -P /Downloads/ -i list.txt
```

Comment: I tried both commands, didn't work :(